# How to use Google Talk without Gmail in Pidgin?

Tags: pidgin, google-talk

I would like use the Google Talk without @gmail.com email address, using my own domain name email address.

- My domain is example.com
- My email address is example@example.com

I'm registering Google Account this email address, but not create Gmail account: gqy@example.com. I would like my email address is pidgin for Google Talk.

I use Debian Wheezy (7.3) and Pidgin (libpurple) 2.10.6.  Tried using [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/26072/how-to-setup-a-google-talk-for-your-domain-account-in-pidgin/) but did not work.

How to use Google Talk with Google Account, but without Gmail?

I don't use Google Apps for my domain name.

Very thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Google support article](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/159495?hl=en) a GMail account is required to use Talk from a 3rd party client:

> Note: A Gmail account is required to use Google Talk or other download
>   clients.